# Vector Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

If vector consists from these numbers `55 55 55 55 1 23 45`, how I am possible to print the number who repeat itself for more then once, so basically **it should print:** `55, 1, 23, 45`.

Comment: Add everything to a `std::set` (which doesn't allow repeats), then print that.

Comment: @CoryKramer Haven't have any experience with std::set, may you explain it further. Many thanks!

Comment: [More information about `std::set`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), be sure to read it.

Comment: member that repeat itself more than 1 = 55 only no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggested, you can use a `std::unordered_set` or `std::set`:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::unordered_set<int> tempSet;
   std::vector<int> vec { 55, 55, 55, 1, 23, 45 };
   for ( auto& val : vec )
   {
      if (!tempSet.count(val)) 
         std::cout << val << " "; 
      tempSet.insert(val); 
   }
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/bBkbmp)

For each item in the vector, the `set::count()` is used to determine if the item is already in the set.  If not in the set, then print the value.

Edit:
I could have placed the `insert()` call within the `if()`:

```
      if (!tempSet.count(val)) 
      {
         std::cout << val << " "; 
         tempSet.insert(val); 
      }
```

but I placed it outside the `if()` to demonstrate that the `set` will not store duplicates, even if you tried to store them.

Comment: Thanks, It worked! Not sure about few things how it worked... but thanks anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminKljuno What are you not sure about?  I will explain it, but the code is pretty straightforward.  Output the value only if it isn't in the set.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why my question got negative reputation, but thanks everyone for comments, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
int sample[]= {55,55,55,55,1,23,45};
std::set<int> myset(sample, sample + sizeof(myset));
for(set<int>::iterator iter=myset.begin(); iter!=myset.end();++iter) cout<<(*iter)<<endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: `sample + sizeof(myset)` Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

basically,

```
vector <int> b;
b.push_back(55);
b.push_back(55);
b.push_back(55);
b.push_back(25);
b.push_back(23);
b.push_back(2);
set <int> a;
for (auto it : b) a.insert(it);
for (auto it : a)
cout << it;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.